# If I run this text as just a script it runs fine. Whats wrong with this syntax in regards to a Tkinter environment?

Tags: python, tkinter, hex

```py
num1=input("Enter a hex value")
num2=input("Enter a hex value again")

sum=hex(int(num1, 16)+int(num2,16))

print(num1)
print(num2)

sum=sum.replace("0x","")
print (sum)
```

Comment: what it is showing in tkinter environment when you run it??

Comment: @WaltHansen tkinter is more of a library then an environment. It is used to make GUIs. For a basic tutorial on how to use tkinter look at the basic examples [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111235321/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20200802160725/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm)

Answer (score -1):

I actually found the answer...  from muddling through it....

def hexadd():
global hnum2
global h2
hnum2 = e.get()
h2 = ("0X") + (hnum2)
sum = int(h1, 16) + int(h2, 16)
sumh = (format(sum, '02X'))
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, sumh)

## where h1 was defined in the previous function, i.e., getting the first number in the equation